# Laravel implicit model binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, http-response-codes

In my Laravel 5.1. application I use Implicit Model Binding. But i want to ask how can i provide custom response in case the resource being accessed doesn't exist in the DB? So when the resource is not found i get:

```
404 Not Found
"class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
```

I tried to change the render method in Handler.php under /app/Exceptions with the following code

```
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            dd('model not found');
            //$e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

Nothing has changed and dd method didn't have any impact. I changed my code into:

```
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            dd('model not found');
            //$e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

And also nothing changed. i still received the same response when the resource i'm trying to access doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.1, implicit model binding is performed in RouteServiceProvider:

```
$router->model('user', 'App\User'); // for binding {user} to App\User model
```

If you wish to specify your own "not found" behavior, pass a Closure as the third argument to the model method:

```
$router->model('user', 'App\User', function () {
    dd('model not found');
});
```

More info in Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding